# Translating the name of a type of beam from Russian to English

Tags: structures, beam, terminology, building-design

I am trying to translate the name of a special kind of beam from a set of Russian-language drawings.

The dictionary translates the name as simply supported beam, but it's not that simple. There is a slight difference in two kinds of beams. First - what is called a **simply supported beam**:

> A beam that lies freely on two supports and covers one span.

Second - **my beam**. This one is different from the previous that it lies on multiple supports and covers many spans.

*Important note: both of the beams are not continuous; i.e., they are parts of one long beam.*

The question is, what would I call the second beam?

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with a sketch of your situation? The expected bending moment diagram would make this much easier to understand. Your description ("beams are not continuous i.e. they are parts of one long beam") is contradictory. If a single beam covers multiple spans, then it is defined as a continuous beam.

Comment: I'm not an engineer, but I've got a whole bending moment calculation. But it's in Russian. Will it help if I upload it?
[Here](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=102f4d08d1&view=att&th=15bf7d6b7c39f628&attid=0.2&disp=safe&realattid=f_j2kho8xi2&zw)

Comment: I'm not following that link. Feel free to take a screenshot or copy-paste it into your question (by clicking the "[edit]" button beneath it). All we need is the final result, not the entire calculation.

Comment: I added the screenshot. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you asking how to describe a beam which has two supports, but those supports are not at the ends of the beam (i.e. there is an overhang beyond each support)? Or are you asking something different?

Comment: Yeah, you say your beam "lies on multiple supports and covers many spans", but the beam you've shown us only lies on two supports, not "multiple." Is this beam representative of what you're asking about (two supports, one large span and a cantilever at each end)?

Comment: I suppose that the beam in the calculation is the one I need. Two supports on both ends and the other beam is something hypothetical and a result of misunderstanding caused by wrong spelling.
So that would be simple supported beam. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also considered a simply-supported beam. If you want to be more descriptive, you can call it a simply-supported beam with overhangs (the cantilevers beyond the main span).

Basically, any beam which rests only on two hinged supports (allowing rotations) is considered simply supported. Beams which rest on more than two supports are considered continuous (so long as all the spans are covered by the same beam):

[image]